# Is it possible to derive a distance time graph from a displacement time graph?

Tags: kinematics, velocity, speed, distance

If I take the derivative of a displacement-time function, it will give the function of its velocity over time. If I take the absolute value of my velocity function it will give me a function of its speed over time. If I take the integral of my speed function will it therefore give me a distance-time function?

Comment: One point is what you call distance. Let's say it starts on point A and ends on point B. The integral of speed won't be the distance between A and B. It will be the total traveled distance, like a kilometer counter in a car.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you mentioned in the description of your question is completely correct.  A displacement-time graph completely describes the location of an object, so you can drive anything from it.  However, there's one more complication: if the object is allowed to move in more than 1 dimension, then displacement-time graph would have to be more than 1 dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

No, since taking absolute value of velocity loses direction information, and that matters in 2 or more dimensions.

Consider a point moving along a 2D circle at speed $c=1$. $\int_0^t c(t) dt = t$, but the distance from the starting point will be $d(t)=(\cos(t)-1)^2+\sin^2(t)$ which is behaving very differently.

If your position is $\mathbf{x}(t)$ (a vector function of time), the displacement function from some origin point will be $d(t)=||\mathbf{x}(t)-\mathbf{x}(0)||$ (a scalar function). Your velocity is $\mathbf{v}(t)=\mathbf{x}'(t)$ (a vector function), your speed is $c(t)=||\mathbf{x}'(t)||$ (a scalar function). But the integral $\int_0^t c(t) dt \neq d(t)$ in general, despite $\int_0^t \mathbf{x}'(t) dt = \mathbf{x}(t)$.